# TikZ, place cylinder in 3D space

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

In [Ti*k*Z manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), cylinders are said to be "a 2-dimensional representation of a cylinder". The result is that they can be `rotate`d only in a plane.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw[->] (0,-4,0) -- (0,4,0) node[above right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (-4,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[below right] {$y$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,4) -- (0,0,-4) node[below right] {$z$};
  \node (a) [draw, cylinder, shape aspect=1.8, rotate=180, minimum height=25mm, minimum width=12mm] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

**Question 1**

Using Ti*k*Z, currently the cylinder axis coincides with the labelled `y` axis. How to make it coincide with the `z` axis instead? Any value given to `rotate` can not achieve this.

---

I also tried this code with `tikz-3dplot`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

\draw[->] (0,-4,0) -- (0,4,0) node[above right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (-4,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[below right] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,4) -- (0,0,-4) node[below right] {$z$};

\node (a) [draw, cylinder, shape aspect=1.8, rotate=180, minimum height=25mm, minimum width=12mm] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But the result is very unsatisfying:

[image]

**Question 2**

How to draw this with `tikz-3dplot`?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `transform canvas` for that.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw[->] (0,-4,0) -- (0,4,0) node[above right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (-4,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[below right] {$y$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,4) -- (0,0,-4) node[below right] {$z$};
  \begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=45}]
  \node (a) [draw, cylinder, shape aspect=1.8, rotate=180, minimum height=25mm, minimum width=12mm] {};
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice, however, that this is a 2D object, so do not expect too much, and `transform canvas` comes with a price, to see that try e.g. `\draw[->] (a.south) -- ++(-1,-1);`. You'd be better off if you use e.g. `tikz-3dplot` for this.

As for your 3dplot question: I guess you need to draw the cylinder by hand.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

\draw[->] (0,-4,0) -- (0,4,0) node[above right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (-4,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[below right] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,4) -- (0,0,-4) node[below right] {$z$};

\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,samples=180] ({cos(\x)},-1.25,{sin(\x)});
\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=-45:135,samples=180] ({cos(\x)},1.25,{sin(\x)});

\foreach \x in {135,-45}
{\draw ({cos(\x)},-1.25,{sin(\x)}) -- ({cos(\x)},1.25,{sin(\x)});}
%\node (a) [draw, cylinder, shape aspect=1.8, rotate=180, minimum height=25mm, minimum width=12mm] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The angles `-45` and `135` are just guessed, not optimal, and need to be adjusted when changing the view angle. This *could* be automatized but would certainly deserve a new question.

Comment: It works and thank you. Again, I can not realize the differences between Ti*k*Z and a specific `tikz-3dplot` code. I edited the question with a new attempt with `tikz-3dplot`. It was not good, because I don't know it well. If you want, you can update your code, too, with a `tikz-3dplot` alternative example.

Comment: @BowPark I made an update to explain in more detail what I mean. Ultimately it boils down to the statement that Ti*k*Z doesn't have a true 3D engine. So you either have to cheat or switch to asymptote.